# Escaping single quotes in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jstl

I am using `fn:escapeXml` to escape quotes in a javascript function. This works perfectly with double quotes however it doesn't work with single quotes.
Below is the html code:

```
 <button class = "location" 
   onclick = "locationModelMethod('${fn:escapeXml(listItem.getBaseRate())}','${listItem.getCreateDate()}','${listItem.getId()}','${listItem.getUser().getEmployeeId()}','${listItem.getChecker().getEmployeeId()}','${listItem.getStatus()}', '${listItem.getRemarks()}' ,${listItem.isActive()})" >
${fn:escapeXml(listItem.getBaseRate())}
 </button>
```

The error occurs when `${listItem.getBaseRate()}` contains a single quote.
I am getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Can anybody help me out with this

Comment: That looks like a pain to write and debug, why not attach the handler properly using Javascript instead? (`addEventListener` or assign to `onclick` property)

Comment: You're writing out the onclick *attribute string*, which is as bad as `eval`, and *not* the same thing as assigning a Javascript function to the `onclick` *property* of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template literals inside function parameters doesn't work. You will need to simply provide parameters.

For example:

```
myFunc(`${myVar}`)
```

Can be simply used:

```
myFunc(myVar)
```

Also, don't attach inline handler as suggested by CertainPerformance in the comment.

**Example including parameters being passed**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    // Parameters that get passed into function being fired by onclick
    var myParam = 'param';

    function myParameterFunction() {
      return 'functionParam';
    }

    function myParameterFunctionWithParams(foo) {
      return foo + 1;
    }
  </script>

  <button onclick="myFunction(myParam, myParameterFunction(), myParameterFunctionWithParams(2))">
      Click me!
    </button>

  <script>
    function myFunction(a, b, c) {
      console.log('fired', a, b, c)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```